# no puedo navegar entre las paginas .php de mi sitio, lo estoy haciendo con php y bootstrap 4

Tags: php, bootstrap

Estoy usando una plantilla de internet hecha con Bootstrap y php.
tengo el archivo layout.php que carga el header, el contenido de cada pagina y el footer.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <title>lllllllll</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="lllllll" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet preload" href="assets/css/css/main.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet preload" href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery.modal.min.css" />
        <link rel="icon"  href="favicon.ico" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->

    </head>
<body>
<header>
    <?php
        require_once('layouts/header.php');
    ?>
</header>

<section>

    <?php
            // carga el archivo routing.php para direccionar a la página .php que se incrustará entre la header y el footer
            require_once('routing.php');
     ?>


</section>

<footer>
    <?php
        include_once('layouts/footer.php');
    ?>
</footer>
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="dist/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="dist/js/scrollspy.js"></script>
<script src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
<script src="dist/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="dist/js/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

en require_one('routing.php');
```

La plantilla por defecto carga el routing.php código de abajo.

```
<?php 

    if ($_GET['menu']=='about') {
        require_once('page/about.php');
    }if ($_GET['menu']=='services') {
        require_once('page/services.php');
    } 
 ?>
```

pero no me carga about.php por defecto ni navega a services.php (ambas estan en la carpeta pages, about.php y services.php

el menú del header.php está asi:

```
<li class="menu-li"><a class="menu-a" href="?menu=about">Nosotros</a></li>
<li class="menu-li"><a class="menu-a" href="?menu=services">Servicios</a></li>
```

Como inyectar en layout.php el contenido de cada pagina con php?????
gracias.

Comment: estoy usando apache2 en un linux, tengo que configurar algo en apache para que me funcione el menu y me cambie de archivo about.php a service.php??

Comment: he activado el modrewrite pero ni asi.......